# Passing Parameter To Bash Shell Script Through Input Redirection (<)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So, I need to write a shell script that accepts a file path as an argument and uses it within the shell script. I know that I could do something like:

```
$ ./script filename
```

With this solution, this would make it so that I could access this filename string using `$1` in the shell script.
However, I'm wondering if it is possible to use input redirection instead so I could pass the filename using it:

```
$ ./script < filename
```

If so, how would I access this filename in the shell script? 
I'm fairly new to shell script coding so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the name of file passed with `<` by listing `/proc/<pid>/fd` directory, as follows:

```
ls -ltr /proc/$$/fd
```

Then

```
$ cat myscript.sh
ls -ltr /proc/$$/fd
$ ./myscript.sh < hello
total 0
lr-x------ 1 u g 64 Feb 25 08:42 255 -> /tmp/myscript.sh
lrwx------ 1 u g 64 Feb 25 08:42 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 u g 64 Feb 25 08:42 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 u g 64 Feb 25 08:42 0 -> /tmp/hello
```

I can't guess whether this is useful

And doesn't work when input is passed through a pipe

```
$ cat hello| ./myscript.sh 
total 0
lr-x------ 1 u p 64 Feb 25 08:50 255 -> /tmp/myscript.sh
lrwx------ 1 u p 64 Feb 25 08:50 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 u p 64 Feb 25 08:50 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------ 1 u p 64 Feb 25 08:50 0 -> pipe:[82796]
```

Alternatively, you can use lsof and a little line handling to extract value

```
 filename=$(/usr/sbin/lsof -p $$| grep " 0u"| cut -c 60-)
```

Comment: nice one, hadn't thought of that... not sure if that's portable, but neat trick all the same... come to think of it, the same could be achieve parsing the output of `lsof -p $$`.

Comment: @isedev Thank you, `lsof -p $$` seems more portable. It's possible too to use lsof to follow pipes, but it seems as useless as the basic case

Comment: Is it possible to translate `/proc/$$/fd/0` to the actual file name passed?

Comment: filename=`/usr/sbin/lsof -p $$| grep " 0u" cut -c 60-` works for me

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the `filename` in the case of `./script < filename` but only its contents. The reason is that the shell opens `filename` and set the corresponding file descriptor to be the standard input of the `./script`.

Answer (score 1):

With your second solution you don't access the filename, but your script's standard input is coming from the file.

With the first solution printing the file would look like this:

```
cat "$1"
```

With the second:

```
while read line; do echo "$line"; done
```

Comment: should be `while IFS= read -r line;`, and you're also missing quotes around $line (`echo "$line"`) .